# How to store properly a BigDecimal in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, bigdecimal

i have this big problem, i have a input where i format my amounts like this.

15,550.55, the problem is that once i submit that value it store it as 15.50 because of the BigDecimal Object, it is not taking the whole number.

In my Parameters Im recieving that value as `"dr_business_remuneration"=>"15,550.55"`

The type of data in my postgresql DB is Numeric(19,2) for that attribute

The only thing i want is that once a submit the value be stored as 15550.55, but be shown in my view as 15,550.55.

i tried with a method in my model with a before_save callback, that erase my "," before saving that value.

```
before_save: montos_formateados

  def montos_formateados
    if !self.dr_business_remuneration.blank?
       self.dr_business_remuneration.sub(",", "").to_f
    end
  end
```

but returns this error.

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Comment: Your substitution happens in the model. It is no longer a string but has already been converted into what the database expects. Try to create a private controller method that sits in `controllers/application.rb` You may also check that : https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency or https://rick-moore.medium.com/formatting-number-strings-in-ruby-4da35d5282e3

Comment: Hello Arturo, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please share the code where you instantiate/create your model so that you get `15.50` from `"15,550.55"` as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. First, if you want it coded to show in terminal correctly, this should work:

```
'15550.55'.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).join(',').reverse
```

If you're displaying it on a webpage, this is the best:

```
<%= number_with_delimiter(@number, :delimiter => ',') %>
```

If you're OK with a few additional dependencies, this is probably the best way:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions'

number = 15550.55
number.to_s(:delimited)      # => "12,345"
number.to_s(:delimited) # => "12,345.6789"
```

I hope that helps!